# On the construction of convex $n$-gons with convex $(n-k)$-gons

Tags: geometry, polygons

I am trying to determine how many convex $(n-k)$-gons, with their vertices in general position and such that at most they pairwise intersect in one vertex, guarantee that we can construct a convex $n$-gon using only the vertices of the convex $(n-k)$-gons.

I would like to know if there are some known results, literature in the subject, or some useful lemmas and theorems that you could share to help me.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

An example of what I mean for $n=4$ would be to ask how many triangles (convex $(4-1)$-gons) such that their vertices are points in general position (no more than two in the same line) and such that at most they pairwise interesect in one vertex, guarantee that we can construct some convex cuadrilateral using only the vertices of the triangles.

In this regard, it is easy to show that two triangles guarantee that we can construct some convex cuadrilateral, as five points in general position guarantee the construction of some convex cuadrilateral (as proved in the context of the [the happy ending problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_ending_problem)).

Indeed, the question is somewhat related to this last problem, adding the constraint of local independent convexities to the points in general position.

Comment: I can't understand this problem properly. What exactly do you mean by "vertices in general position" or "pairwise intersect"? Can you be a little more elaborate? Maybe, add a diagram or an example to the question.

Comment: "Vertices in general position" means that that no more than two of them are on the same straight line. "At most pairwise intersect in one vertex" means that the $(n-k)$-gons, considered two by two, intersect at most in one vertex. Hope to have clarified it!

Comment: It's still not really clear to me what you want to know. Can you just add an example of a case that's valid and an example of one that's not? I hope, that would make things clear enough to give it a try.

Comment: @SayanDutta I have edited the OP with an example of what I mean, hope it is clear enough now!

Comment: @JuanMoreno: By "$n$-convex polygons" do you mean "convex $n$-gons" (ie, "convex $n$-sided polygons")? If not, then what is your definition of "$n$-convex"? I'm not familiar with the term.

Comment: @Blue my fault, I mean "convex $n$-gons"; already edited the term. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @JuanMoreno Yes, now the question is clear enough, but I still don't have an idea of how to solve it. As far as I know, The Happy Ending problem still doesn't have a slution for the general case (although a formula was hypothesized by Erdos). Considering that, it doesn't seem one more added constraint would yield anything :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

This answer proves the following two claims :

Let $g(n,n-k)$ be our number. (For example, one has $g(4,3)=2$ which you've already pointed out.)

**Claim 1** : $g(5,4)=3$.

**Claim 2** : For $n\geqslant 5$, $g(n,3)\geqslant n+1$.

---

**Claim 1** : $g(5,4)=3$.

*Proof* :

According to the [Happy ending problem (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_ending_problem#Larger_polygons), one has $f(5)=9$ where $f(N)$ is the minimum $M$ for which any set of $M$ points in general position must contain a convex $N$-gon. Therefore, $g(5,4)=3$ follows.$\quad\blacksquare$

---

**Claim 2** : For $n\geqslant 5$, $g(n,3)\geqslant n+1$.

*Proof* :

Using the first figure in [Juan Moreno's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4231918/78967), one can see that five triangles ($ABE$, $EFH$, $CGH$, $BFC$, $ACD$) do not guarantee the construction of some convex pentagon. This implies that $g(5,3)\geqslant 6$. Next, using the second figure, one can see that six triangles ($ABF$, $FGI$, $CHI$, $BGC$, $ACD$, $EDJ$) do not guarantee the construction of some convex hexagon where the way of the construction of the first five triangles is the same as the one used in the first figure. Using this idea inductively, one can see that for $n\geqslant 5$, $g(n,3)\geqslant n+1$.$\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: thanks for your answer! Indeed, it seems that building on the figures I proposed there can be settled lower bounds for every $g(n,k)$; I will work on it!

Comment: it seems that in your second claim, when you state $g(n, n-3)$, you mean $g(n, 3)$, as you are always referring to triangles... is it possible?

Comment: @Juan Moreno : I've changed the notation $g(n,k)$ to $g(n,n-k)$ since the notation $g(n,k)$ was misleading. Thanks for pointing it out. I think that your figures are very nice, and I agree with your first comment. I'll work on it too.

Comment: thanks! I like your notation, I edit my answer to use the same one.

Comment: @Juan Moreno : Using a similar argument as the one for $g(n,3)$, I got $g(n,4)\geqslant\left\lceil\dfrac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil$ though I don't think that this is a good lower bound.

Comment: @matholove I got strong evidence that $g(n,4)≥n−2$, I post it as an answer; I would be grateful if you could assess the possibility of applying induction to this case as for your proof of the case $g(n,3)$

Answer (score 1):

Working on the lower bounds, using the figures of my [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4231918/567304), I have the following

**Conjecture:** $g(n,4) \geq n-2$

*Bases of the conjecture:*

From two pentagons there can be drawn three quadrilaterals as showed in the picture, so $g(6,4)\geq 4$:

[image]

From two hexagons there can be drawn four quadrilaterals as showed in the picture, so $g(7,4) \geq 5$:

[image]

From two heptagons, there can be drawn five quadrilaterals as showed in the picture, so $g(8,4) \geq 6$:

[image]

From two octogons, there can be drawn six quadrilaterals as showed in the picture, so $g(9,4) \geq 7$:

[image]

From two nonagons, there can be drawn seven quadrilaterals as showed in the picture, so $g(10,4) \geq 8$:

[image]

There is enough evidence of a pattern of construction, but as it is not as clear as for the proof of the lower bound for $g(n,3)$ provided by [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/78967/mathlove), it is not so clear to me that we can inductively conclude that $g(n,4) \geq n-2$.

Comment: Very nice! Let us name the way of the construction of $AIRJ,IHGF,EDCA$ in the figure for $g(10,4)$ as $s,t,u$ respectively. Then, for $n=3m+6$, you can take $s,t,u,s,u,s,\cdots, u,s$. For $n=3m+7$, you can take $s,u,s,u,s,\cdots, u,s,t,s$. For $n=3m+8$, you can take $s,u,t,u,s,u,s,\cdots, u,s$.

Comment: Great @mathlove, well seen! Then we have proved that $g(n,4)\geq n-2$. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! Your idea is very nice. I couldn't find it.

Comment: For $n-k\geq 5$ it seems that the initial figures do not allow to continue this inductive argument to find good lower bounds; do you have any idea?

Comment: I agree with you. I don't have any good idea. It seems difficult to connect the points on the left with the points on the right. I've just got $g(n,5)\geqslant 2\left\lfloor\dfrac{n-2}{4}\right\rfloor+1$ which is not a good lower bound.

Comment: According to [Happy ending problem (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_ending_problem), $f(6)=17$ has been proved by Szekeres & Peters (2006). I think that there should be an arrangement of $16$ points where no convex hexagons are possible. Also, you might want to see [Happy ending problem (MathWorld)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HappyEndProblem.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a partial answer, to show that, if we denote as $g(n, n-k)$ the number of convex $(n−k)$-gons, with their vertices in general position and such that at most they pairwise intersect in one vertex, that guarantee that we can construct a convex $n$-gon using only the vertices of the convex $(n−k)$-gons, we can state that, for $n\geq 5$ $$3\leq g(n, n-1)$$

As stated in the OP, two triangles guarantee the construction of some quadrilateral. However, we can have two quadrilaterals that do not guarantee the construction of a convex pentagon as follows:

[image: Two Quadrilaterals]

We can have two pentagons that do not guarantee the construction of a convex hexagon as follows:

[image: Twp Pentagons]

It is easy to see that, generalizing this method of construction opposing the convex hulls of the two polygons for every convex $n$-gon, we can have two convex $n$-gons such that they do not guarantee the construction of a convex $(n+1)$-gon. Therefore, for $n\geq 5$ $$3\leq g(n, n-1)$$

Erdös-Szekeres conjecture, if true, would set the upper bound $g(n, n-1)\leq \lceil\frac{2^{n-2}+1}{n-1}\rceil$; however, I conjecture that the true upper bound must be much lower.